# Erro ao retornar itens não repetidos e em ordem alfabética

Tags: c

O código se encontra na imagem.

Enunciado:"Valentina é uma mulher muito dedicada e costuma trabalhar até tarde todos os dias. Para economizar tempo, ela faz a lista de compras do mercado em um aplicativo e costuma anotar cada item na mesma hora que percebe a falta dele em casa.

O problema é que o aplicativo não exclui itens duplicados e como Valentina é distraída, anota o mesmo item mais de uma vez e a lista acaba ficando extensa. Sua tarefa como programadora e amiga de Valentina é melhorar o aplicativo de notas desenvolvendo um código que exclua os itens duplicados da lista de compras e que os ordene alfabeticamente.

Entrada
A primeira linha de entrada contém um inteiro N (N < 100) que indica a quantidade de casos de teste que vem a seguir, ou melhor, a quantidade de listas de compras que Valentina quer organizar. Cada lista de compra consiste de uma única linha que contém de 1 a 1000 itens ou palavras compostas apenas de letras minúsculas (de 1 a 20 letras), sem acentos e separadas por um espaço.

Saída
A saída contém N linhas, cada uma representando uma das listas de compras de Valentina, sem itens repetidos e em ordem alfabética."

[image: Código feito que está dando erro]

A sugestão do erro é que tenha a ver com algum vetor que está com menos capacidade do que necessita ou estou tentando acessar uma memória inválida, mas não faça ideia de como consertar isso.

Me ajudem, por favor!

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, amigo.
O erro em seu código esta na seguinte linha:
 **if(!strcmp(vi[i], vi[i + 1]) == 0)**
Ele esta gerando um estouro de endereço na memoria quando chega ao final do vetor. 
Verifique as variaveis dos contadores, como **l1** colocando o programa de debug line-to-line.
Espero ter lhe ajudado.